# when to use min-max-scalar and standard-scalar

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

When it is referred to use [min-max-scaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) and when [Standard Scalar](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).
I think it depends on the data. Is there any features of data to look on to decide to go for which preprocessing method.
I looked at the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#scaling-features-to-a-range) but can someone give me more insight into it.

Comment: [This might be helpful](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html)

Comment: I have input features in data in the range(0,1) with some features containing outliers. Which preprocessing method is preferred?

Comment: [Z-score standardization or Min-Max scaling?](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html#z-score-standardization-or-min-max-scaling)

Answer (score 5):

The scaling will indeed depend of the type of data that you will. For most cases, `StandardScaler` is the scaler of choice. If you know that you have some outliers, go for the `RobustScaler`.

Then, you deal with some features with a weird distribution like for instance the digits, it will not be the best to use these scalers. Indeed, on this dataset, there a lot of pixel at zero meaning that you have a pick at zero for this distribution involving that dividing by the std. dev. will not be beneficial. So basically when the distribution of a feature is far to be Normal then you need to take an alternative.

In the case of the digits, the `MinMaxScaler` is a much better choice. However, if you want to keep the zero at zeros (because you use sparse matrices), you will go for a `MaxAbsScaler`.

NB: also look at the `QuantileTransformer` and the `PowerTransformer` if you want a feature to follow a Normal/Uniform distribution whatever the original distribution was.

Comment: What's the difference between StandardScaler and QuantileTransformer with output_distribution='normal' ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.
When to use MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler, StandardScaler, and Normalizer
https://towardsdatascience.com/scale-standardize-or-normalize-with-scikit-learn-6ccc7d176a02

Answer (score 1):

#### StandardScaler

**StandardScaler** assumes that data usually has distributed features and will scale them to zero mean and 1 standard deviation. Use `StandardScaler()` if you know the data distribution is normal. For most cases, **StandardScaler** would do no harm. Especially when dealing with variance (PCA, clustering, logistic regression, SVMs, perceptrons, neural networks) in fact Standard Scaler would be very important. On the other hand, it will not make much of a difference if you are using tree-based classifiers or regressors.

#### MinMaxScaler

**MinMaxScaler** will transform each value in the column proportionally within the range [0,1]. This is quite acceptable in cases where we are not concerned about the standardisation along the variance axes. e.g. image processing or neural networks expecting values between 0 to 1.

---

- [Guide to Scaling and Standardizing](https://www.kaggle.com/code/discdiver/guide-to-scaling-and-standardizing/notebook)
- [Compare the effect of different scalers on data with outliers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html)